# Idle up and down while in gear at a stop light but not in park or neutral

Tags: nissan, rough-idle

Rpm jumping up and down when stopped in gear but runs perfect when in park or neutral. Not throwing any codes. 06 nissan frontier

Comment: Do you notice any other issues, stalling, rough starts, is it down on power or inefficient?

Comment: How many rpm is it jumping?